# Validation for Google form

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am a teacher, and I use Google Forms to make exams for my students. I want to prevent any one who is not in my classes to enter the form, the problem is I need a JavaScript to make it work. Could any one please make it for me?

I have been looking up for it on the internet, but no one work with me.

I have found this, but it does not work.

```
function idValidation() {
  // get the form directory 
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();

  var user_ids = "92984270353|5449205725|437147249";

  // create the validation rule
  
  var pattern = "^" + user_ids + "$";
  var idVal =  FormApp.createTextValidation().requireTextContainsPattern(pattern).build();

  form.getItems()[0].asTextItem()
  .setHelpText("Inserisci un codice identificativo valido.")
  .setValidation(idVal)
  .setTitle("title");
}
```

The var user_ids is where I have my students IDs, when I tried this, it showed me this message:

`Exception: Invalid conversion for item type: SECTION_HEADER.`

I do not have experience in programming and I need help to make this code work. I want the user to enter the user_ids in first page in the form, if it is included in the script it will let him/her continue the exam.

Comment: You have an illegal curly quote here: `|437147249”; <<<<`

Comment: You need matchesPattern: `var idVal = FormApp.createTextValidation().requireTextMatchesPattern(pattern).build();`

Comment: Thank you for replying, I do not know to fix it I am not a programmer, could you fix it for me, please?

Comment: I just did. @varad_s already changed the quote for you, replace the word Contains with Matches. If that does not work, please hire a developer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to prevent any one who is not in my classes to enter the form.

This would require the user to be validated BEFORE they reach the form.

> Note that in Google Forms, user-interface elements are visible only to
> an editor who opens the form to modify it, not to a user who opens the
> form to respond.

See documentation:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs

Here is a simple script you can test for yourself that it works for the editor view of a form, but not for the responder view of the form:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  const ui = FormApp.getUi();
  const response = ui.prompt('Getting to know you', 'May I know your name?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  // Process the user's response.
  if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.YES) {
    Logger.log('The user\'s name is %s.', response.getResponseText());
  } else if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.NO) {
    Logger.log('The user didn\'t want to provide a name.');
  } else {
    Logger.log('The user clicked the close button in the dialog\'s title bar.');
  }
}
```

As you can see, it is not possible to use apps script to validate users before they can reach the form.

However, you can either:

- Use the first question on the form to validate an entered value by switching on "Response validation" for a "Short answer" question.
- Use settings that are available in the Workspace account to prevent any user who does not have a Workspace account from accessing the form.

You should contact your account administrator for assistance with that.

https://support.google.com/a/answer/6208960

If necessary, the account administrator can contact Google Support from their Workspace Admin Console.